# Track time spent in application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

What should I use to track how long is user using my application on iOS devices?

I think I can do it like this:

1. Log time on App startup (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`)
2. Log time on App ending (`applicationWillTerminate:`)
3. List item

Send report (pairs of start/exit time) to server and count time spent in app

Do you have any better ideas?

Important is to be network and resources effective
(not to send big amount of data or consume iOS resources on complex computing operations.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that `applicationWillTerminate:` is not necessarily called when the home button is pressed (this changed from iOS 3.X to iOS 4.0).

Take a look at `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that calculating the time on the device itself would be best, considering you want this to be network and resource effective. The calculation of endTime - starTime will be very very fast (depending on your time implementation), and then you would only need to send one piece of data (the time it took) over a network instead of two (the start and end times).

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Comment: and send it every time user closes app? that could be very non-user-comfortable and network-effective, isn't it?

Comment: You could either do that, or you could save the information and send it the next time the user opens the app. Either way you'll have to send it while the user is using the app.

Comment: Isn't it better to collect data over a time and send them in like a week period? or month period?

Comment: You could. In fact, you could collect it over a month's period. What I'm saying is basically about WHAT you're sending. If you send times, you need to send at least two data structures (start and end times), while if you send the time spent, you only need to send one (number of seconds or minutes or etc.), and the calculation is very fast and simple. I'm suggesting you do the calculation on the phone instead of on the server.

However, the "when" you send it would be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable way to do it. It's efficient enough, and depending on how you see the data, it shouldn't be more than a kilobyte or two, if that. Be wary of privacy issues though—users are really against being logged.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is sound, it will have next to no overhead and get the job done nicely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log time on App startup (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)
2. send report often with interval of 5min.
3. send report in applicationWillEnterbackground.(pause timer(invalidate) if u used background thread for it).because if the user enter in other app then they can close ur app by just using home button and with minus button in app manager.so u have to send report here also
4. resume timer with previous time in applicationWillEnterForeground.
5. Log time on App ending (applicationWillTerminate)
6. Send report (pairs of start/exit time) to server and count time spent in app

Comment: on point 3+4, you could just keep the timer running and just set the variable  (e.g. int secondsSpent) to zero on next load from applicationWillEnterForeground. On 5 + 6, applicationWillTerminate won't grant enough time to send the data up to the server, so would need to log it locally on the device and send on next launch.