# Is there a way to measure the total time the user has spent in my app?

Tags: ios, time, metrics

I am making a game and would like to have a statistics page from my users. Is there a way for me to track their total amount of time that they have spent in my app?

Comment: Instead of manually doing it, you can make use of Analytic's APIs (Flurry, Google Analytics, etc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track time spent in application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765945/track-time-spent-in-application)

Comment: Have you tried or researched anything yet? Please do so before posting a question, otherwise you're just asking people to do all your work fo you. At the very least you could use the normal view lifecycle methods to track the time between a user starting or bringing your app to the foreground and exiting or putting the app in the background, then save that to user defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flurry Analytics: http://www.flurry.com/

Getting Started: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart

Integration is very simple, just do this:

```
#import "Flurry.h"
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[Flurry startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
//your code
}
```

To log event:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];
```

Answer (score 0):

as radesix writes you need a metrics framework. In the company I work for we use Google Analytics. It gives a pretty good overview and is very easy to use:

To start it up

> ```
> // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
> [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
> // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
> [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
> // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
> [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
> // Create tracker instance.
> [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"YOUR TRACKING ID"];
> ```

To track an event:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
 [tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"TITLE" withAction:@"paused" withLabel:@"success" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
```

Read more at http://www.google.com/analytics/